# The distribution function of X+

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

Let's assume that we have a symmetric density function around $y$ axis, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(X\leq 0)=\mathbb{P}(X\geq 0)=\Phi(0)=0.5$ where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the distribution function of $X$.

$$y^+=\max(y,0)$$

Is this approach correct?

Let $x\geq 0$
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\mathbb{P}(X^+\leq x)=\mathbb{P}(\max(X,0)\leq x)=\\
&&\mathbb{P}(X< 0)\times \mathbb{P}(\max(X,0)\leq x \vert X< 0)+\mathbb{P}(X\geq 0)\times \mathbb{P}(\max(X,0)\leq x \vert X \geq 0)=\\
&&\frac{1}{2}\times \mathbb{P}(\max(X,0)\leq x \vert X< 0)+\frac{1}{2}\times \mathbb{P}(\max(X,0)\leq x \vert X\geq 0)=\\
&& \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\Phi(x)
\end{eqnarray} 
Does $X^+|X$ has the same distribution as $X$?

Can we infer that
\begin{eqnarray} 
\Phi_{X^+}(z)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\Phi(z),&& \mbox{  if  }z\geq 0\\
&&\\
\Phi_{X^+}(z)=0,&& \mbox{  if  }z< 0
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: However, what I get empirically, is 
$$\Phi_{X^+}(z)=\Phi(z),\quad \mbox{if }z\geq 0$$
and
$$\Phi_{X^+}(z)=0,\quad \mbox{if }z< 0$$

Answer (score 2):

You need to be more careful in calculating the second part:

$$ \mathbb{P}(\max(X,0)\leq x|X \geq 0) = \frac {\mathbb{P}(X\leq x, X \geq 0) }{\mathbb{P}(X \geq 0)} = 2\left(\Phi(x) - \frac {1} {2}\right)$$

and thus you will obtain the result agree with your empirical finding.

Note that $X^+$ is a (measurable) function of $X$, so $X^+ \in \sigma(X)$ and thus $X^+|X$ has the same distribution as $X^+$